# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: AccessDenied

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am currently trying practice on Django. 
I am trying to do

`python manage.py collectsatic`

However, I keep getting the errors like below.

raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

my settings.py code for this issue is as below.

```
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = #Access ID 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = # ACCESS KEY 
AWS_REGION = 'ap-northeast-2' 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = # Bucket Name 
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME 
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400', }
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION) 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I seriously do not see as to why I keep getting the access denied as I believe I put the correct codes in the settings.py.

I referred to couple of threads on this matter, I tried what the others tried to resolve the case. However, it seems like my case is not getting resolved.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this right?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The issue is likely not with your settings, but with the permissions on the API key you are using. Show us the IAM policy associated with this key.

Comment: Also, "I referred to other threads and tried things" isn't a good way to show that you've put in some effort yourself. You should show us what you've tried, and what didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I figured it out. Yes. you were right it was due to AWS setting. The S3 group was not set up with policy setting. The policy name should have been 'AmazonS3FullAccess'. This was not applied when I created the group. I changed this in AWS setting and staticfiles have been collected now. Thank you for your help and advice.

Comment: I will show more details when I post the questions next time. Thank you so much for your advice. I am still quite newbie in this :(